# facebook sharing in wordpress, showing unusual description with no image

Tags: facebook, wordpress

here is my post: http://blog.hfarazm.com/node-js-tutorials/
when i share it on facebook, it gives me this:
[image: screen shot]

Issue: no image is loading plus description is not right. i m using wordpress, with yoast plugin. what is the solution to it? i tried fixing it for days now but its not working. I used this code in wordpress: 
`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=1443948685857569" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:20px; width: 144px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your site to serve different content to Facebook than to a web visitor or other web services.

When I plug your site address into the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.hfarazm.com%2Fnode-js-tutorials%2F) and click on "See exactly what our scraper sees", it shows this content only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body><p>      }v۸sV9;Ejl˲lgN&gt;{s(S$:Gܗ
-rV $KrzoKP(
BG&gt;xĆ|w{?g=Cg{F0hC$lW FwX;Zw~xbЎbo-U!G.A uO7釨;$
ϒn}oٷ4  "vT\E3(7g~F
AWu٠V]wR5ۑȋC    {|g{L{&amp;,zCSңԧ8qlzjd~T?ا</p></body>
</html>
```

Plugging your same URL into the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.hfarazm.com%2Fnode-js-tutorials%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) shows errors with what appears to be your generated HTML.

Check to make sure you don't have a plugin that's messing with served content. This looks like something an anti-content scraper might do.

Failing that, talk to your hosting provider and find out if they're "optimizing" your site somehow for Facebook.

Comment: the word optimizing clicked for me. I installed a plugin named as : "w3 total cache", i deactivated it and went to facebook debugger and fetched new data and everything went well. Thanks mate.